# can't remove hover effect on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my code:

```
$('.ratings_stars').hover(
    // Handles the mouseover
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).addClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('ratings_vote');
    },
    // Handles the mouseout
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().removeClass('ratings_over');
        $(this).removeClass('ratings_over');
    }
);

$('.ratings_stars').click(function() {
    $('.ratings_stars').unbind('mouseout');
    $(this).off('mouseout');
    console.log('rating star clicked!')
    var star = this;
    var widget = $(this).parent();
    $(this).prevAll().addClass('ratings_over');
    $(this).addClass('ratings_over');
    var clicked_data = {
        clicked_on: $(star).attr('class'),
        widget_id: widget.attr('id')
    };
});
```

i have tried .unbind and .off but mouseout still has an effect? help? i wanted to add class of ratings_over on previous elements and the target element on click, and disable the hover's mouseout effect.

Comment: You are trying to remove/unbind a `mouseout` handler when you haven't attached one - you've attached a hover.

Comment: @Adam i tried $('.ratings_stars').unbind('hover'); but nothing's changed, hover is still functioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike all of the events when unbinding `hover` you should use `mouseenter mouseleave`

```
$('.ratings_stars').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```